# Allen's IntersectsWith operator in q

Tags: kdb

I am trying to benchmark Allen's IntersectsWith temporal operator in q on the latest kdb+.  Allen's IntersectsWith temporal operator is the union of 11 of the 13 relational interval algebra operators he defines.  In effect, it returns all overlapping intervals plus any that touch the ends of the interval.  (In this sense, it doesn't exist as a primitive temporal operator).

I have a table holding instrument measurements over an interval `(startDate,endDate)` - the size of the interval can be dynamic but in the below example it is one minute intervals:

```
queryPeriods:dataFieldStartDate`dataFieldEndDate!(2019.01.01T00:00:00.000000000; 2019.01.02T00:00:00.000000000)
```

```
dataValues:`datafield`startDate`endDate!(`inst1_m`inst1_m`inst1_m;2019.01.01T00:00:00.000000000 2019.01.01T00:01:00.000000000 2019.01.01T00:02:00.000000000; 2019.01.01T00:01:00.000000000 2019.01.01T00:02:00.000000000 2019.01.01T00:03:00.000000000)
```

```
queryPeriods
dataFieldStartDate            | dataFieldEndDate 
-----------------------------   -----------------------------
2019.01.01T00:00:00.000000000 | 2019.01.02T00:00:00.000000000
```

```
dataValues
datafield | startDate                     | endDate
---------   -----------------------------   -----------------------------
`inst1_m  | 2019.01.01T00:00:00.000000000 | 2019.01.01T00:01:00.000000000 
`inst1_m  | 2019.01.01T00:01:00.000000000 | 2019.01.01T00:02:00.000000000
`inst1_m  | 2019.01.01T00:02:00.000000000 | 2019.01.01T00:03:00.000000000
```

I'm somewhat familiar with wj window-join operator, but I'm not a "q God" by any means, and I'm not sure how to do a wj on a row containing an interval.  Alternatively, I was thinking of modeling the interval using the [Relational Interval Tree](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/businessanalytics/using-static-relational-interval-tree-time-intervals/) data structure and indexing/keying on the "fork node", but then I lose the benefits of the wj.

While sample data here is small, my objective is to eventually benchmark 20B rows.

EDIT: Here is a SQL query that replicates what I want to do, plus the output of the query.  You can also [run the SQL on rextester](https://rextester.com/GRYO14651), but since its constructed using CTEs, it requires no special permissions to run on SQL Server.

```sql
;WITH QueryPeriods AS (
    SELECT
        DataFieldStartDate = CAST('2019.01.01 00:00:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2),
        DataFieldEndDate = CAST('2019.01.02 00:00:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2)
), DataValues AS (
    SELECT
        datafield = 'inst1_m',
        startDate = CAST('2019-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2),
        endDate = CAST('2019.01.01 00:01:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        datafield = 'inst1_m',
        startDate = CAST('2019.01.01 00:01:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2),
        endDate = CAST('2019.01.01 00:02:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        datafield = 'inst1_m',
        startDate = CAST('2019.01.01 00:02:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2),
        endDate = CAST('2019.01.01 00:03:00.0000000' AS DATETIME2)
)
SELECT
    qp.*,
    dv.*
FROM QueryPeriods qp
    LEFT JOIN DataValues dv
        ON dv.datafield = 'inst1_m'
        AND dv.startDate < qp.DataFieldEndDate AND dv.endDate > qp.DataFieldStartDate
```

OUTPUT:

```
DataFieldStartDate  DataFieldEndDate    datafield startDate           endDate
01.01.2019 00:00:00 02.01.2019 00:00:00 inst1_m   01.01.2019 00:00:00 
  01.01.2019 00:01:00
01.01.2019 00:00:00 02.01.2019 00:00:00 inst1_m   01.01.2019 00:01:00 
 01.01.2019 00:02:00
01.01.2019 00:00:00 02.01.2019 00:00:00 inst1_m   01.01.2019 00:02:00 
 01.01.2019 00:03:00
```

Comment: Could you also provide the desired output after application of Allen's 11 relations.

Comment: Updated with output and also a SQL query.  Note that QueryPeriods might not be contiguous. For example, an analyst might want to see instrument data for the first of every month, or from [(1/1/18, 1/3/18), (1/1/19, 1/3/19)].  There could also be instrument data that spans a full year, e.g. the DataValue row could have an interval (1/1/18, 1/1/19).  In SQL Server, on 1B row sample, I optimized this down to 4-6 minutes without partitions, but the nested loop join time is lousy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple approach(for in-memory table) would be to just iterate over each QueryPeriods and fetch required data. Normally it runs pretty fast and there are certain optimizations that could be done with it.

dv table(DataValues)

```
     datafield   startDate     endDate                      
----------------------------------------------
    ibm 2000.01.01T00:00:03.649z 2000.01.01T00:10:03.649z
    ibm 2011.01.19T12:58:59.098z 2011.01.19T13:08:59.098z
    ibm 2011.01.19T12:59:08.222z 2011.01.19T13:09:08.222z
    ibm 2007.11.11T21:26:07.936z 2007.11.11T21:36:07.936z
```

qv table(Query Values)

```
dataFieldStartDate             dataFieldEndDate
-------------------------------------------------
2011.01.19T13:08:53.604z 2011.01.19T14:09:53.604z
2007.03.05T23:46:47.997z 2007.11.11T21:26:08.938z
```

**Function:**

```
q) raze {[x;y]![select from dv where datafield=x,startDate<y`dataFieldEndDate,
   endDate>y`dataFieldStartDate;();0b;y]}[`ibm]each  qv
```

I tested it on table with 100million rows with same symbol and 2 different query-periods(same table mentioned above), it took 3.8 seconds to execute.

Output:

```
dataField   startDate          endDate                 dataFieldStartDate   dataFieldEndDate                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ibm 2011.01.19T12:58:59.098z 2011.01.19T13:08:59.098z 2011.01.19T13:08:53.604z 2011.01.19T14:09:53.604z
ibm 2011.01.19T12:59:08.222z 2011.01.19T13:09:08.222z 2011.01.19T13:08:53.604z 2011.01.19T14:09:53.604z
ibm 2007.11.11T21:26:07.936z 2007.11.11T21:36:07.936z 2007.03.05T23:46:47.997z 2007.11.11T21:26:08.938z
```

**Optimizations:**

1. **Table attributes**:  Using the correct attributes on columns can help improving the query execution time. I setup datavalues table sorted by startdate,enddate.
2. **Parallel Execution**: Its very easy to run above query in parallel which should also improve the execution time(depending upon system config and KDB setup). If you have slaves running in your KDB process then just use 'peach' instead of 'each' in above query. That will execute different batches of query-periods in different processes.

Comment: Some follow-up: Is your 100M rows for QueryPeriods or DataValues?  In my application, I want to intersect 1.5 qv by 1.5 dv where the dv table is 20B rows.  In SQL, on a 300M row table with partitions, I was able to 130K x 130K intersect in 23 seconds best case, 2:06 worst case (under load). - Thanks for the parallel execution tips.  I am familiar with AquaQ Analytics TorQ and exxeleron to access the results from a managed runtime.  Was thinking I'd need a gateway pattern to scale this.

Comment: 100M DataValues rows. Gateway design would depend on your setup. If it is a single machine then running slaves and using peach would be sufficient. If you are running this on multiple machines then gateway is a good idea. But there are other design changes that you could try with or without gateway, that might improve the performance. 1. Change your query according to your data access pattern. For ex, if you are querying for multi syms and they share same query period then using  query periods in where clause first might help (select...where dv.startdate<qv.enddate,...,sym in ``a`b`c).

Comment: 2. You can control the batches to run in parallel. So for multi sym query, create batch for each sym with all query periods and run that in one thread. That will help reduce cache misses. 3. Partitions - Instead of one table you could divide table into many based on your data access patterns. Partition by symbol or partition by date/time. These changes will help with both designs(single machine or gateway). You need to test different partitions/query format as per your data access pattern to come up with the best one.

Comment: Thanks.  How many qp's were in your join (in other words, how many individual queries)?  Just asking so that when I try it for myself I can see if I'm way off course and under-tuning things/writing something too slow.

Comment: I used qp table with 2 rows(2 query periods) similar to the example I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this tells me what I need to know - Next steps are to implement Relational Interval Tree in kdb and see how well that performs.